# Python checking if the displayed format meets demanded format

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've been playing with Tesseract and I would like the text that is displayed after I run the program to be in a specific format, otherwise, I would like for the program to display an error, but still continue running.

#### Displaying the first item on the list

```py
res3 = split3.split()[0]
```

And I want this first item (`res3`) on the list to be displayed in format `NN.NN.NNNN` (ex. 01.01.2020), else display an error, stating that the format is incorrect.

I would appreciate any help on the matter, as I'm still just a novice to Python :)

Comment: learn regex. `import re` start with pythex

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to regex.
**import re**
start with learning with **regex101** or **pythex**

```
import re

expected = '01-01-2020'
#expected = '01.01.2020'

if re.findall("[[0-9]{2}[-\.][0-9]{2}[-\.][0-9]{4}", expected):
    print("Present")
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this at home. But shouldn't the expected be? expected = "01.01.2020" or is this equal to "01-01-2020"? It makes a difference right?

Comment: @GalBordelius In that case [[0-9]{2}[-\.][0-9]{2}[-\.][0-9]{4}

Comment: I will don't worry, I just have to test it first, otherwise I won't get any other solutions :/ And I would like for the program to still continue running, despite the error and at the end of the program to display where the error occurred.